# Android flag icon for reporting

Tags: android, graphics, icons

I'm looking for a free flag icon for my app, which a user will be able to click on to mark something as inappropriate. The icon should match the standard holo light theme.

Anyone have a link to a free icon I can download. (The flag doesn't appear to be in the standard icon set, which is surprising).

Sorry if this is the wrong place to post this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[AndroidAssetStudio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)** : Lets you create icons conforming to the Android style. Usually, the most common choice for Android developers who don't want to spend too much time on icons. The best part : ***icons are generated for all resolutions (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi) automatically, so saves you a lot of headache***.

---

**[MetroStudio](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio)** : Choose from thousands of templates for popular applications and modify them according to your needs. Change orientation, background color, icon color and size. Probably the best tool for icons I have come across. And like the website says, ***"the icons are available royalty-free and can be used in commercial applications".***

---

**[NounProject](http://thenounproject.com/)** : One of the best websites to find icons and get them in svg format, which you can later modify according to your needs. But you are bound by the **[CreativeCommons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/)** in most of the icons uploaded here. The best part : ***huge collection of icons in svg format which you can use for other development purposes too.*** Anyway, maybe [**this is what you are looking for**](http://thenounproject.com/noun/flag/#icon-No21946) ?